# Function declaration in a loop doesn't evaluate the variable

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to define a zsh function in a batch, using a for loop. I would expect to get different functions, e.g. `pre1post`, `pre2post` etc., each of which referring to the  value of the variable at the moment of function creation.

From what I tried, I get the name of the function correctly but the value used in the loop refers to the last value in the array (as if it was a global variable?).

How can I save the current value of the variable in each defined function?

```
DESCRIPTORS=("1" "2" "3")

for i in $DESCRIPTORS; do
    function "pre"$i"post"() {
        echo i=$i

        local j=$i
        echo j=$j

        eval "k=$i; echo k=$k"
        echo p=${(P)ENV_DESCR}

        eval "value=\"\${$ENV_DESCR}\""
        echo v="$value"

    }
done;

> pre1post
i=3
j=3
k=
p=
v=
```

Comment: Don't use `#!/bin/bash` for a script intended to be executed by `zsh`.

Comment: good point, although doesn't change the outcome (I was just experimenting with stuff)

Answer (score 1):

References to `i` in the body are evaluated when your function is *called*, not when it is defined. `zsh` does not provide closures. See [Is there something like closures for zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94129/is-there-something-like-closures-for-zsh?noredirect=1) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substitution modifier](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) to extract the number from the function name, like `${0:s/pre//:s/post//}`.

`$0`, and therefore `${0}`, refers to the function name, for example "pre1post". The modifier `s/l/r/` generally replaces "l" with "r", or in our case `s/pre//` replaces "pre" with nothing. We can apply multiple modifiers by separating them with colons in order to make multiple of such subsitutions:

```bash
0=pre1post echo ${0:s/pre//:s/post//} # outputs 1
```

Another way would be to use `${0:3:-4}` and work with offsets. `:3:-4` means to skip the first 3 and the last 4 characters, referring to the length of "pre" and "post":

```bash
0=pre1post echo ${0:3:-4} # outputs 1
```