# jquery click function declaration evaluates the variable at runtime

Tags: jquery, function, variables, declaration

I'm trying to create a notification with the css and div [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504931/6319163) .

But I need more than one notification, so I serialized the ids of the divs.

Problem is, when I declare the click function, the variable `nname` doesn't get evaluated - it's only evaluated when I click the dismiss button. So only last notification is dismissed.

How can I declare a function with the value of the variable 'nname'?

I found [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440616/6319163) but it's about zsh.

```
nc = 0;
function show_notification(data){    
    nname = "notification_" + nc
    $('body').append('<div id="' + nname + '" class="notification" style="display: none;"><span class="dismiss"><a title="dismiss notification">x</a></span></div>');
    $('#' + nname).fadeIn("slow").append('some new information');
    $('#' + nname + ' .dismiss').click(function(){$("#" + nname).fadeOut("slow");});
    nc++;
}
```

Comment: I can not solve the main problem you described. Are you also looking for another solution?

Comment: The SO question you need is: [how do closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: could'n find any solution, so i need a solution not another solution. I need to define the function as function(){$"#notification_0).fadeOut('slow2);}

Comment: However, in this case, you do not need an `id` and incremental IDs are a crutch that you will benefit from doing without.   In this case, change to .appendTo then you'll have a reference to the new element without needing to re-select it.  Event delegation would handle the dismiss, with use of `this` and DOM navigation.  Given the limited code / no html, it's hard to be precise (edit: it's `.notification)

Comment: the html needed is given in the append code.

Comment: Yes, just realised that when copying to a fiddle - didn't see it as it was scrolled off the side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the variable `nname` is not unique to each time you call `show_notification` - by not adding `let`/`var`/`const` it becomes a global variable, so when you click the 1st [x] the variable has already been changed to point to the most recent.

While there are ways to handle this, you can remove the need for an incremental ID by using `.appendTo` to give you a variable containing the new content then use jquery methods on that variable.

```
var newDiv = $("your html").appendTo("body");
newDiv.fadeIn();
```

Within the click handler, use `this` and DOM navigation to close the selected popup.

```
....click(function() { 
    $(this).closest(".notification").fadeOut();
});
```

```js
function show_notification(data) {
  var newDiv = $('<div class="notification" style="display: none;"><span class="dismiss"><a title="dismiss notification">x</a></span></div>')
    .appendTo("body");
  newDiv.fadeIn("slow").append('some new information:' + data);
  newDiv.find(".dismiss").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".notification").fadeOut("slow");
  });
}

// Add some notifications
show_notification("1");
setTimeout(() => show_notification("two"), 500);
```

```css
.dismiss { color: red; margin-right: 0.5em; border: 1px solid #FCC; cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, good explanation with timeouts and styles.,
I didnt know about "appendto". That'll stand in hand. 

(you also didnt miss 'data' :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your issue.
I've given the count of your notifications id's in your anchor tag and fetched the same to remove a particular notification.

```js
nc = 0;
function show_notification(){    
    nname = "notification_" + nc
    $('body').append('<div id="' + nname + '" class="notification" style="display: none;"> <span><a title="dismiss notification" class="dismiss" data-id = "'+nc+'" >Close</a></span> </div>');
    $('#' + nname).fadeIn("slow").append('some new information');
    nc++;
}

  $(document).on("click",".dismiss",function() {
      var findid = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $("#notification_"+findid).fadeOut("slow");
  });

show_notification();
show_notification();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about $(this).
$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow') did the trick.

Comment: Glad to know that you found a solution :) keep it up